# Building arm / aarch64 rootfs

Tags: debian, root-filesystem, debootstrap

I am interested to generate a Debian rootfs for aarch64 machine from an x86_64 workstation.
What are the required steps to achieve this ?

As far as I know the proper way is to use debootstrap:

https://wiki.debian.org/es/debootstrap

Is it correct, or there is any other recommended way ?

**EDIT:** my goal is to build a rootfs to be mounted from an ARM device. Precisely, I will install this rootfs on a micro SD card.

Comment: What is the end goal? Do you want to build this new Debian rootfs to stand alone? Effectively installing it to a disk so you can boot off of it? Or do you want to create a chroot to be able to cross-compile things in aarch64 on a x86_64 workstation? Please edit your post to include what your goal is, what you have tried, and what is not working. `debootstrap` can do both of these things but it will help others to know what you are trying to accomplish so as to provide an appropriate answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building your own arm64 Debian port, `debootstrap` will be the best option. There may already exist a working Debian image/tarball/installer for your arm64 board but if you require more granular control over your system, building it yourself will be best.

I am including a link to the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) on `debootstrap` as well as the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debootstrap) for reference.

For more information on arm64 Debian, check out [this Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port).