# qemu-debootstrap error trying to create Rootfs of Debian ARM64

Tags: qemu, debootstrap

I am trying to create a Root file system from last stable version of Debian using `deboostrap` for an `ARM64`-`AARCH64` Architecture. I am using the wiki of Debian [Arm64 Port](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port#Debootstrap_arm64) as a base, which was mentioned in the solution for this similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554391/building-arm-aarch64-rootfs). However, when I am trying to create the rootfs from my Ubuntu host machine, I receive the next error

```bsh
$ qemu-debootstrap --arch=arm64 --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg --variant=buildd --exclude=debfoster stable debian-arm64/ http://deb.debian.org/debian/
I: Running command: debootstrap --arch arm64 --foreign --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg --variant=buildd --exclude=debfoster stable debian-arm64/ http://deb.debian.org/debian/
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 0146DC6D4A0B2914BDED34DB648ACFD622F3D138)
I: Retrieving Packages 
I: Validating Packages
....
I: Running command: chroot debian-arm64/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
W: Failure trying to run:  /sbin/ldconfig
```

As you can see, the problem is in the last commands that the system sends to complete the Rootfs process, but I am not sure why there is a problem trying to run `/sbin/ldconfig` inside of the rootfs.

My idea is to create a Bootable SD Card to star a ARM Processor. I have already compiled the Device Tree and the custom Kernel, but I could not create the `ext4` system with the rootfs because of this problem.

Thank you for your help.

PS: I test the same command for a `amd64` architecture and I did not have any problem.

Edit: This is the last lines in the `debootstrap.log`:

```bsh
2021-11-12 16:17:02 URL:http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.36.1-8_arm64.deb [1096992/1096992] -> "/home/jairom/Downloads/debian-arm64//var/cache/apt/archives/partial/util-linux_2.36.1-8_arm64.deb" [1]
2021-11-12 16:17:02 URL:http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xxhash/libxxhash0_0.8.0-2_arm64.deb [18544/18544] -> "/home/jairom/Downloads/debian-arm64//var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libxxhash0_0.8.0-2_arm64.deb" [1]
2021-11-12 16:17:02 URL:http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.2.5-2_arm64.deb [164528/164528] -> "/home/jairom/Downloads/debian-arm64//var/cache/apt/archives/partial/liblzma5_5.2.5-2_arm64.deb" [1]
2021-11-12 16:17:02 URL:http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xz-utils/xz-utils_5.2.5-2_arm64.deb [218740/218740] -> "/home/jairom/Downloads/debian-arm64//var/cache/apt/archives/partial/xz-utils_5.2.5-2_arm64.deb" [1]
2021-11-12 16:17:02 URL:http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-2_arm64.deb [87944/87944] -> "/home/jairom/Downloads/debian-arm64//var/cache/apt/archives/partial/zlib1g_1%3a1.2.11.dfsg-2_arm64.deb" [1]
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```